# How to test a React Component with a Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given a simple custom hook (which I know how to test):

```
const useCounter = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  const increase = () => {
    setValue(value + 1)
  }

  return {
    value, 
    increase
  }
}
```

And a component that use it:

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { value, increase } = useCounter()

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{value}</div>
      <button onClick={increase}>
        plus
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How do I test the component?
What is the "right way" of doing it?
Do I have to mock the custom hook? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Jest and Enzyme for unit testing, I would wrap the `App` component into a shallow wrapper using [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/)'s [shallow rendering API](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html).

Then, I will use `.find()` to find the `button` element, and use `.simulate('click')` on the element, to simulate an `onClick` event on the button, such that the `increase` method will be called.

After which, I will carry on to check with the expected result and behaviour.

Here is a brief on how it can be done:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';

describe('<App />', () => {

  it('test for onClick', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

    // do the rest here
    // expect().....
  });

})
```

Comment: So, I thought that the correct way of testing is checking that the `increment` function is called on button click.
You are saying I should check that after I press the counter is increased.

maybe...
But that logic is being tested already by the hook test.
So I thought that in my component I should check only the connections, I mean "i press the button and the hook function is called"

Comment: `But that logic is being tested already by the hook test` - it is not so. Let's imagine your component utilizes `useCounter` and even calls `increase()` in some cases but does not render `value` returned(say it renders hard-coded '0'). Even if custom hooks is correct and well tested you still need to verify your component(s) integrate it in correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to mock it. When you run `App` in a test it will just use your custom hook.

If you want to modify it's behaviour somehow specifically for the test, then you would have to mock it.